# Inserting Tyxml_js.Svg values in js_of_ocaml's Dom_svg

Tags: ocaml, js-of-ocaml

Let's say I create an SVG rect, using Tyxml's syntax:

```
let rect_elt = <:svg< <rect></rect> >>
```

How can I insert it inside the DOM using the API of js_of_ocaml ?

I want to do something like that:

```
let _ =
  let rect_elt = <:svg< <rect></rect> >> in
  let svg_elt = Dom_svg.getElementById "graph-svg" in
  svg_elt##appendChild(rect_elt)
```

But I don't know how to do the proper type conversions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so in order to convert to (resp. from) Dom_svg, one has to create an instance of `Tyxml_cast.MakeTo` (resp. MakeOf):

```
module To_dom = Tyxml_cast.MakeTo(struct
  type 'a elt = 'a Tyxml_js.Svg.elt
  let elt = Tyxml_js.Svg.toelt
end)

module Of_dom = Tyxml_cast.MakeOf(struct
  type 'a elt = 'a Tyxml_js.Svg.elt
  let elt = Tyxml_js.Svg.tot
end)
```

and use it as follow:

```
let _ =
  let svg_elt = Dom_svg.getElementById "some-svg" in
  let rect_node = <:svg< <rect></rect> >>
    |> To_dom.of_node in
  svg_elt##appendChild(rect_node)
```